# Install plugin problem with Magento connect

Tags: magento-connect, ssl, magento-connect-manager

I need to install some plugin. I would like to install with magento connect.

In 3 web site (with file hosts modified) when i try to install the message is:

```
community/Vhaldecode_CookieLaw: SSL connect error
```

or

```
community/MailUp: SSL connect error
```

can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

[It's not safe to use Magento connect for installing extension , click this link for more information.](https://www.integer-net.com/why-modules-shouldnt-be-installed-via-magento-connect-manager/)

in the worst case, if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Let me know if you find any problems in this.

**Note** : As this is unofficial 3rd party site, there is no guarantee about security. but i tested many extensions, i did't faced any security problems....

Comment: then i must to install manually,correct? but the error? You Can Fix tris?

Comment: you are getting error at the time of installing extension through `magento connect` right? , so if you upload extension manually, i dont think you will face any problem, its all about copy pasting.